# How to handle null values in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am comparing data between two rows in a table because i want to know in which columns where are the differences. So i have written a code with SQL Server's XML Features.

For example, i have created a table which contains FirstName, LastName and BirthDate. The data come from different sources. And I would like to make sure that both sources provide me with the same data. If it is not the case, I will indicate in my result which columns are concerned and their values

```
Id    Source    FirstName    LastName    Birthday
1     1         Toto         Titi        2001-01-30
1     2         Totos        Titi        NULL
```

As you see, i have a null value on birthday column. *** My question : How to compare null value with a data in xml ***. Thanks for your help

My SQL Code :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id int,
    Source int,
    FirstName varchar(100),
    LastName varchar(100),
    Birthday Date
)
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
VALUES(1, 1, 'Toto', 'Titi', '2001/01/30'), (1, 2, 'Totos', 'Titi', NULL)

-------------------------
with A
as (
 select Id, Source,  (
         Select  *
         from    dbo.MyTable
         where   Id = pp.Id and Source = pp.Source
         for xml auto, type) as X
 from dbo.MyTable pp
 )
--select * from A

, B
as (
    select  Id, Source
        ,   X.query(
         'for $f in dbo.MyTable/@*
          return 
        <MyTable name="{ local-name($f) }" value="{ data($f) }" />
      ') as X2
 from A
 )
--select * from B

, C
as (
 select B.Id as ID, B.Source
  , norm.MyTable.value('@name', 'varchar(max)') as Name
  , norm.MyTable.value('@value', 'varchar(max)') as Value
from B
 cross apply B.X2.nodes('/MyTable') as norm(MyTable)
)
--select * from C

-- Result
select C1.Source, C1.Id, C1.Name as ColumnName, C1.Value as ColumnValue
from (select * from C) C1
full outer join (select * from C) C2
    on C1.Name = c2.Name and C1.ID = C2.ID
where c1.Value <> c2.Value and C1.Name <> 'Source'
order by C1.ID, C1.Name
```

The result of this code :

```
Source    Id    ColumnName    ColumnValue
1         1     FirstName     Toto
2         1     FirstName     Totos
```

**In the result, i would like to see Birthday in ColumnName and their values**
This is my expected result :

```
Source  Id  ColumnName  ColumnValue
1   1   Birthday    2001-01-30
1   1   FirstName   Toto
1   2   Birthday    NULL
2   1   FirstName   Totos
```

Comment: Please don't post data as an image, post it as **formatted** `text`. As for your question, what is it? You've stated you have a problem with `NULL`, but not said what result you or after, or what your question is. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55118133/edit) your question and replace the images with text, ask a question, and explain the results you are after. Thanks.

Comment: Also, `NULL` is "handled" by XML. If a column/row has a value of `NULL`, it isn't displayed in the XML; that is how it is handled as it has no "known" value. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c85ee7665e0f253915b14be02f8057a).

Comment: thx. It's edited

Comment: So, what is your expected result here? you seem to have omitted that,.

Comment: As i said, i would like to display null value in xml. Because i need to see it in my final result.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of expected results, here's a guess; I doubt you even need XML to achieve you're goal (if I understand correctly):

```
SELECT MT.Source,
       MT.Id,
       V.ColumnName,
       CASE V.ColumnName WHEN 'FirstName' THEN MT.FirstName
                         WHEN 'LastName' THEN  MT.LastName
                         WHEN 'Birthday' THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),MT.Birthday,103)
       END AS ColumnValue
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,'Firstname'),(2,'LastName'),(3,'Birthday'))V(N,ColumnName)
ORDER BY MT.Source,
         MT.ID,
         V.N;
```

Comment: i have added my expected results at the end of my post. I need XML because i don't want to specify column names in my SQL request. I would like that my SQL request work for any table (structure is different for each table) . Thx for your helping

Comment: Why is `Surname` missing from the dataset @Maxime1984? How do you determine which columns should be "skipped"?

Comment: because i want to see only data which are different between the two sources. There is no difference on Last Name so i don't need to display it.